# PDFlib - add SVG from string

Tags: pdflib

Is it possible to add SVG graphics to PDF page from string when working with PDFlib?

Documentation states that `load_graphics()` takes file name on disc. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you can use PVF (PDFlib Virtual Filesystem) for this task. See PDFlib 9.2 Tutorial, chapter 3.1.3 "*The PDFlib Virtual File System (PVF)*" for a detailed introduction.

A sample for using this with a raster image is included in the PDFlib packages (**starter_pvf.php**) and also included in the PDFlib cookbook:
[starter_pvf](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/general/starter_pvf/php/).

```php
    # We just read some image data from a file; to really benefit
    # from using PVF read the data from a Web site or a database instead

    $imagedata = read_file("../input/PDFlib-logo.tif");

    $p->create_pvf("/pvf/image", $imagedata, "");

    # Load the image from the PVF
    $image = $p->load_image("auto", "/pvf/image", "");
```